# wget parameters.yml from non-publics S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently moved my app to elasticbeanstalk, and i am running Symfony3, there is a mandatory parameters.yml file that has to be populated with Environmental variables.

Id like to wget the parameters.yml from a private S3 bucket, limiting access to instances only.

I know i can set the environmental variables directly on the environment, but i have some very very sensitive stuff there, and environmental variables get leaked into my logging system, which is very bad.

I also have multiple environments such as workers using the same environmental variables, and copy pasting them is quite annoying.

So i am wondering if its possible to have the app wget it on deploy, i know how to do that, but i cant seem to configure the S3 bucket to only allow access from instances.

Comment: Use `aws s3 cp` to get the file and an instance role to authenticate the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that definitely can be done, there are different ways of doing this depending what approach you want to take. I would suggest to use `.ebextentions` to create IAM Role -> grant access for that role to your bucket -> after package is unzip on the instance -> copy object from s3 using instance role

1. Create custom IAM role using AWS console or using `.ebextentions` [custom resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) and grant access for that role to the objects in your bucket. 
   Related [read](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/)
2. Using above mentioned `.ebextentions` set [aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration) in `options_setting` to specify instance profile you created before.
3. Again, using `.ebxtentions` use [container_commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) option to run `aws s3 cp command`